# Invalid pointer (TypeError) when using FFI::ManagedStruct

Tags: ruby, ffi

I am writing a library using Ruby-FFI, and want to take advantage of the cleanup functionality offered by FFI::ManagedStruct.

I am replacing e.g. `MyStruct < FFI::Struct` with `MyStruct < FFI::ManagedStruct` and adding `def self.release(ptr)` as per the [documentation](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Examples). However, when running my code now, I get this error:

```
[...]autopointer.rb:68:in `initialize': Invalid pointer (TypeError)
```

This happens where I try call a function declared with attach_function, passing a `FFI::MemoryPointer` to the struct in question. When using `FFI::Struct`, it works fine.